# Matlab 2015 font size in Help browser

Tags: matlab, fonts, settings

I have Matlab R2015a. The font size in the [Help browser](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/doc.html) is too small and there are no options to increase it. They say use ctrl and +, but as soon as you navigate, the font is back to its miniature size.

Is there a way to increase the font permanently? I know that some settings can be changed by code, but I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: Might interest you: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/242403

Comment: To clarify, do you mean the plain-text help in the Command Window or the HTML-formatted documentation? I.e., `help help` vs. `doc doc`. These are two distinct things.

Comment: @brodroll Thank you very much! That's it. I had to edit site5.css and doc_center.css as explained in the link. Please add an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @horchler I mean the HTML-formatted doc.

Comment: The table of contents still had the small fonts. I edited `doc_center.css` and commented out all `font-size` properties `(/*font-size:1.05em;*/)` under `TOC Styles`. Now, all fonts are good.

Comment: Did as you mentioned. Glad it helped

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The help font size can be tweaked in the *site5.css* and *doc_center.css* as you mentioned. Quoting Hans R's post from [this discussion](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/242403):

> For lasted versions of matlab, there is no 'HTML Proportional Text '
> option.
>
> Low level control of help font size can be found within:
>
> %matlabroot%\help\includes\product\css\site5.css
>
> /* Page Globals */  html { min-height:100%; margin-bottom:1px; }  html
> body { height:100%; padding:0px; margin:0px; font-family:Arial,
> Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:62.5%; color:#000; line-height:140%;
> background:#fff; overflow-y:scroll; }
>
> " change 'font-size:62.5%' to something larger, e.g. 'font-size:100%'

For code environment:

> code environment is tweaked in the style file doc_center.css (same
> folder as site5.css). Search for the line:
>
> /* Fix for  from site5, deprecating  */ code { padding:0px;
> margin:0px; color:inherit; font-size:12px; border:none;
> background:transparent none; display:inline; }
>
> I deleted the font-size setting from this line, which allowed the
>  environment to be set by the default  setting in
> site5.css.

Which should change Matlab's font size in the help window.

Comment: And for the Table of Contents in help: I edited `doc_center.css` and commented out all `font-size` properties (`/*font-size:1.05em;*/`) under `TOC Styles`. Now, all fonts are good.

Comment: This should be used for code environment: `code { padding:0px; margin:0px; color:inherit; /*font-size:12px;*/ border:none; background:transparent none; display:inline; }` in doc_center.css

Comment: For the pane, I had to change the font manually (not just remove) in .toc_container_wrapper { font-size:11px; line-height:130%; }

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the blodoll's answer.

In the same file `%matlabroot%\help\includes\product\css\site5.css`

There are three lines

```
* html pre { font-size:1.1em; }
* html tt { font-size:1.1em; }
* html code { font-size:1.1em; }
```

where the stars indicate comments. Uncomment those by deleting stars, and adjust the sizes the way you like it. 
If you don't have those lines, may be you could try adding them.

My `site5.css` has, among others, following code in it:

```
/* New Reset */
/* Reset */
pre { font-size:100%; }
tt { font-size:100%; }
code { font-size:100%; }

pre { font-size:1.2em; }
tt { font-size:1.2em; }
code { font-size:1.2em; }

html pre { font-size:1.1em; }
html tt { font-size:1.1em; }
html code { font-size:1.2em; }

pre { *font-size:1.1em; }
tt { *font-size:1.1em; }
code { *font-size:1.1em; }
pre { font-size:1.0em\9; }
tt { font-size:1.0em\9; }
code { font-size:1.0em\9; }
```

Which kind of suggests, that matlab developers used it to replace the depreciated `reset.css`. If yours `site5.css` doesn't have it, put it there and adjust the way it suits you.

Answer (score 0):

I used this way on MATLAB 2016a and fortunately it works correctly.

To adjust the font size in the Help browser or MATLAB web browser, right-click the page and select Zoom In or Zoom Out. You cannot change the font type or style